# How do I a read text file's content from the web in Visual Basic 6.0 line by line?

Tags: vb6

I need source code for reading the .txt content from a URL.

My text file content sample and then load in Visual Basic 6.0:

[image: http://gigpars.com/upload/tpm_untitled-3.jpg]

My source code:

```
Dim data As String
data = Inet1.OpenURL("http://test.com/sample.txt")
Text1.Text = data
```

Comment: Further to my answer, the textbox will not show multiple lines by default. To show this correctly, set the `MultiLine` property to true, and make sure the source data used CRLF line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that will only "download" a line at a time as it can't tell where the line breaks are until it's downloaded it.

If you only want to read/process a line at a time, you can split on the line breaks after downloading it:

```
Dim Data As String
Dim DataLines() As String

Data = Inet1.OpenURL("http://test.com/sample.txt")
DataLines = Split(Data, vbCrLf)
For Index = LBound(DataLines) to UBound(DataLines)
  MsgBox DataLines(Index)
Next
```

You will need to be careful to make sure you have the correct line break for the data being read.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with HTTP you have to consider both line separators and character encoding.  If you can make assumptions after testing then you can bypass some checking and just hard-code to fit your needs.

However the creay old Internet Transfer Control ("Inet") is usually not the best choice available and more modern alternatives are shipped as part of Windows since at least the advent of IE 5.5, and installed with IE 5.5 on more ancient versions of Windows.  Thus they'll even be available and work on nearly any Win95 system still running today.

```
'References to MSXML 3.0 or later,
'              ADO 2.5 or later.

Private Function GetHttpText(ByVal URL As String) As ADODB.Stream
    Dim Req As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim CharSet As String
    Dim CharsetPos As Long
    Dim LineSeparator As LineSeparatorEnum

    Set Req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set GetHttpText = New ADODB.Stream
    With GetHttpText
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        With Req
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .send
            CharSet = LCase$(.getResponseHeader("CONTENT-TYPE"))
        End With
        .Write Req.responseBody
        CharsetPos = InStr(CharSet, "charset")
        If CharsetPos Then
            CharSet = Split(Mid$(CharSet, CharsetPos), "=")(1)
        Else
            'UTF-8 is a reasonable "default" these days:
            CharSet = "utf-8"
        End If
        If CharSet = "utf-8" Then
            LineSeparator = adLF
        Else
            'Your milage may vary here, since there is no line-end
            'header defined for HTTP:
            LineSeparator = adCRLF
        End If
        .Position = 0
        .Type = adTypeText
        .CharSet = CharSet
        .LineSeparator = LineSeparator
    End With
End Function

Private Sub DumpTextLineByLine()
    With GetHttpText("http://textfiles.com/art/simpsons.txt")
        'Read text line by line to populate a multiline TextBox
        'just as a demonstration:
        Do Until .EOS
            Text1.SelText = .ReadText(adReadLine)
            Text1.SelText = vbNewLine
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```